# Accordion with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, function, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to implement an accordion with jQuery, however I am having a problem. When I press the button it is supposed to `slideToggle` the info but instead it is just sliding in and out.

I don't know why it's behaving this way, I am learning and I will appreciate if someone could help me with this.

This is my JavaScript:

```
$(".wrap-faq  a").on("click",accordion);

function accordion() {
    if($(this).attr("class") != "active"){
        $(".wrap-faq  li  p").slideDown();
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $(".wrap-faq a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
       }
}
```

I also leave the link to my JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zZaTf/

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in JQuery UI [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)?

Comment: I've found slideToggle to be quite erratic. Maybe try using slideUp and slideDown?

Comment: Hi Jhonnatan, did you resolve this issue? If so, could you post your answer? Many thanks :)

Comment: yea! i finally found the way...i will post it to you tomorrow at work, because i actually dont have the code her, i will upload it in a jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You have `display: none` on `.txt-ans-faq` class and `slide...` effect will not work on a hidden element. Well, it will, but you won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

As Ilia notes, `display: none` will prevent you from seeing your content text, so get rid of that for a start. You can hide all the content by calling an initial `slideUp()`.

The actual `slideToggle` can be implemented simply in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.txt-ans-faq').slideUp(0);

  $('.wrap-faq  a').click(function(e) {
        $(this).next().find('.txt-ans-faq').slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SiCurious/zZaTf/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I updated the script accordion the Simon.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.txt-ans-faq').slideUp(0);

  $('.wrap-faq  a').click(function(e) {
         $('.txt-ans-faq').slideUp(300);      
        $(this).next().find('.txt-ans-faq').slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zZaTf/9/